# Fly to Cart for Opencart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencart, shopping-cart

I have following code to implement fly to cart for Opencart.

Problem : On clicking AddtoCart first time, no product flies to cart - but product gets added successfully. On clicking AddtoCart second time, product flies to cart (THIS IS WHAT I WANT). On clicking AddtoCart third time, two clones of image flies to cart and so on.

Can someone please point out mistake in my code below.

```
function addToCart(product_id, quantity) {

    quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;
i = 10;
    $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
        //alert(this);

            $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information, .error').remove();

            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            }
            //alert(this);
//alert("button is clicked");
            if (json['success']) {
            alert(this);
//alert("button is clicked");
            $('.button').click(function () {
//      alert("button is clicked");
        adt = $(this);
        var cart = $('#cart');
    //  alert (this);
        var imgtodrag = $(adt).parent().siblings(".image").find("img").eq(0);
        //alert (this);
//      alert(imgtodrag);

      if (imgtodrag) {
//alert(imgtodrag);

        i = i + 30;
            var imgclone = imgtodrag.clone()
                .offset({
                top: imgtodrag.offset().top,
                left: imgtodrag.offset().left
            })
                .css({
                'opacity': '0.5',
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'height': '150px',
                    'width': '150px',
                    'z-index': '100'
            })
                .appendTo($('body'))
                .animate({
                'top': cart.offset().top + 10,
                    'left': cart.offset().left + i ,
                    'width': 75,
                    'height': 75
            }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');

            /*setTimeout(function () {
                cart.effect("shake", {
                    times: 2
                }, 200);
            }, 1500); */

            imgclone.animate({
                'width': 15,
                    'height': 15
            }, function () {
                $(this).detach()
            });
        }
    });
        //      $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
            }   
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you add to `$('.button').click` event ONLY after a product has been added to the cart (at least from the code above). I would personally create a function that creates that event for that button. Your code will become:

```
function bindButtonClick() {
    $('.button').off('click').click(function () {
        adt = $(this);
        var cart = $('#cart');
        var imgtodrag = $(adt).parent().siblings(".image").find("img").eq(0);

        if (imgtodrag) {

            i = i + 30;
            var imgclone = imgtodrag.clone()
                .offset({
                    top: imgtodrag.offset().top,
                    left: imgtodrag.offset().left
                })
                .css({
                    'opacity': '0.5',
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'height': '150px',
                    'width': '150px',
                    'z-index': '100'
                })
                .appendTo($('body'))
                .animate({
                    'top': cart.offset().top + 10,
                    'left': cart.offset().left + i ,
                    'width': 75,
                    'height': 75
                }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');

            imgclone.animate({
                'width': 15,
                'height': 15
            }, function () {
                $(this).detach()
            });
        }
    });
}

function addToCart(product_id, quantity) {

    quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;
    i = 10;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {

            $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information, .error').remove();

            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            }

            if (json['success']) {

                bindButtonClick();

                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now, the function bindButtonClick has to be called on domready

```
$(function(){
    bindButtonClick();
});
```

Also, note the `$('.button').off('click')` which unbinds your previous click, so that it doesn't get triggered multiple times.

**Notes:**
- instead of `alert`, try to learn your browser's developer tool, use `console.log` instead ([Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) in Firefox and [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index) in Google Chrome). You will not have the nagging alert and you can see in console all your javascript errors.

Comment: This works almost perfectly for me. Thanks. However, have one issue - the first item does not fly instead it is quietly added to cart. Second click onwards it works perfectly.

Comment: Did you put the `$(function(){ bindButtonClick(); });` inside your html? That is what makes it 'fly' the first time. Look in my answer!

Comment: Now have one more question,if I am not bugging you too much. I want to always show the product which are added onto cart. So I have commented out detach() function above. Now products clone get added as i want them. however, On pressing Enter, the added product clone list goes off. I want to keep the product clones added, to be always shown.

Comment: That feature must be done with php. There must be a loop there (in the view). Inside that loop create another one with the quantity of the current product. This way, on page refresh or form submit, you will get the same product listing.